# How do I check the value of a form input that is set by a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, validation

This is on a product review page which we recently had a developer make some changes to.  The ratings used to be styled radio buttons which were easily validated, but the developer changed them to look like this:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="setvaluenew(10);" title="5 stars out of 5" class="five-stars">10</a></li>
```

the function `setvaluenew` is written as:

```
 function setvaluenew(newval)
 {
     if(newval=='6'){  percentage = '20%';}else if(newval=='7'){  percentage = '40%';}else if(newval=='8'){  percentage = '60%';}else if(newval=='9'){  percentage = '80%';}else{  percentage = '100%'; }
     $jj("#secretrating").val(newval);
     $jj("#current-rating").css('width',percentage);
     $jj("#current-rating").css('margin',"0px")
 }
```

and `#secretrating` is a hidden input field for the review form that has a default value of `""`

They work but I am trying to restore the validation mechanism.  Since they are no longer radio buttons, I'm trying to understand what this function does and how to retrieve the value to validate it.

I have tried to use this to check the value during validation:

```
var rated = 0;
var ratingValue = $('#secretrating');
...
if (ratingValue != "" )
    rated = 1;
```

but it passes validation even if a rating is not chosen.  I also tried `$('#secretrating'.value)` with the same result...`rated` ends up equal to `1`

Comment: Have you tried `var ratingValue = $jj('#secretrating').val();`  ?

Comment: @kei [edited]  that DOES work, the first time I tried it I goofed a parenthesis.....Thank you so much!

Comment: @kei Is `$jj` a jQuery method, or is it defined by some other javascript elsewhere?  I'm slightly out of my depth here (but learning)

Comment: It seems `$jj` has been defined as the alias for the jQuery function in your code.